# Texturing problem with models

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have 2 models within my blender. i Want to put on my horse model simple jpg texture like on my turtle.[image: TUrtle-horse] Theres any way to do that? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Hi, those image don't look like textures...? They seem more sketches/outlines of the actual 3d model... the turtle example could somewhat be useful to add some pattern on the model, but the horse...? where should the black lines go on your model...? Detail more what you're trying to achieve, maybe show an example or reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that.

You can use some [Projection painting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQy5jn9dWrs), or some [stencil painting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1rhn_ma9Wo), or use the [UV Project modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html), or hand paint the texture yourself (since it's a few black strokes on white background, I think it's actually the fastest and easier way to go).